# How to convert big time from H:i:s to H:i without fatal error?

Tags: php, datetime

I have mysql column `workTime2` with value `838:59:59`. I get the value from the database and use with this code:

```
$work2MinutesStr = $employeeWork->workTime2;

if (strlen($work2MinutesStr) == 0) {
    $work2MinutesStr = '00:00:00';
}

$work2Minutes = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $work2MinutesStr);
$work2MinutesStr = $work2Minutes->format('H:i');
```

But code fails on the last line with error: `Fatal error:  Call to a member function format() on a non-object`

DateTime type works well, but can't handle such values.
Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: Try this: `echo date('H:i', strtotime($work2MinutesStr));` after the if statement

Comment: Why is there 838 hours?

Comment: @JoachimMartinsen, Flight time of a particular employee on a certain aircraft type. Need it in hours.

Comment: So what are you expecting `$work2MinutesStr` to be in the end if it starts out with `838:59:59`?

Comment: @JoachimMartinsen, If you can do it in mind, why the machine can't? I say this code works in 99% of time, except this situation. Why I can't use 2000 hours, for example?

Comment: Because you are working with dates. There's only 24 hours in a day.

Comment: But what are you trying to do? Are you only trying to remove the seconds?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that sometimes you have over 838 hours in total and it is out of the mysql time range. There is no format that would process three digit hour in php, so you get the error.

1) I think you need to convert your time to seconds in your sql query and work with seconds.

2) Then you can divide seconds by 3600 and get total hours.

UPDATED

> By default, values that lie outside the TIME range but are otherwise valid are clipped to the closest endpoint of the range. For example, '-850:00:00' and '850:00:00' are converted to '-838:59:59' and '838:59:59'.

[Manual link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html)

So when you get `838:59:59` hours it already means that you get incorrect hours. May be you have over 900 hours, but you only get `839` because of the limitation of the time value in MySQL. But let's say that the number (`839`) is correct. When you read this value in php  and try to use DateTime class in php USING `h:i:s` format, the DateTime class CAN'T process correctly this string (`838:59:59`) because of the INCORRECT time format. And the format is incorrect bacause it has **THREE** digit number in hours. So when you try to call this method `$work2Minutes->format('H:i');` it will say that `Call to a member function format() on a non-object` because DateTime couldn't convert the string to an object.

That's way you need to work with SECONDS or other time type in order to get the right time and process it correctly.

Comment: No problem on mysql side, also no problem with DateTime with `H:i:s` format of this value. I dont't need seconds, because I'm already have hours.

Comment: So..what solution can help here (for hours over 838)? considering that already thousands of lines recorded in this format

Comment: You need to try to convert time to seconds using time_to_sec() function in your sql query. Then in php you will manually divide seconds by 60*60 and you will get the total number of hours. You will need to format it manully if you'd like to have 3 digit number in hours

Comment: I'm about DB storing (to put data over 838 hours)... INT type with minutes number?

Comment: Sorry, I don't clearly understand you. Can you post some sample data from your database where you store Times?

Comment: [Screen](https://imgur.com/XCHA5yl). I mean what type of mysql I need to use to store time data? Because sometimes values must be over 838.

Comment: You can use the same field type (time), but when you query your data you need to use time_to_sec() function in you sql query. Like that: SELECT sum(time_to_sec(workTime2)) AS totalWorkTime FROM yourtable WHERE condition. You will get the number of seconds in PHP. Then you can divide this totalWorkTime by 3600 and you will get the total number of hours.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your hours into days and then remove the day hours?

```
$timeParts = explode(':', $work2MinutesStr);
$hours = $timeParts[0];

$days = floor($hours / 24);
$daysHours = $days * 24;

$timeParts[0] = $timeParts[0] - $daysHours;

echo $timeParts[0] . ':' . $timeParts[1];
```